# Setting button size in centimeters - auto layout on any device

Tags: user-interface, button, unity-game-engine, uibutton, autolayout

I would like to add a button to my opening screen in my Unity game.

I'm trying to find out how can I set its size in centimeters (instead of pixels) and make it look this size on any device without taking care of the device's screen resolution.

Is there a way for doing that? I've been struggling with this for quite sometime.

Thank you folks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the new Unity UI (UnityEngine.UI) you can set add a [CanvasScaler](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html) and set the mode to "Constant Physical Size".

If you aren't you can do this manually:

[Screen.dpi](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-dpi.html)

[Screen.width](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-width.html)

[Screen.height](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-height.html)

Use these to calculate pixels/cm in each dimension then calculate your button size in pixels. Note that Screen.dpi can return 0 if the dpi can't be determined.

Comment: Could it be that in Unity there is not a built in feature for that? Not that its complicated but that's weird as this program usually has a built in feature for almost everything. Thanks

Comment: It turns out there is... CanvasScaler includes a " Constant Physical Size". I didn't realise this until I double checked! I'll update the answer.